# formidable doesnt work with express

Tags: node.js, express

**Before you wast any time** : *please note that this is a reference question , just in case some one needed it. but please feel free to correct me :)*

so , im trying to use formidable (i know that it's so similar to `bodyParser` and that i should be using body parser instead ! ) with express . the problem that it doesnt work at all .

here is simple part of my code (relevant part )

```
    form.on('progress', function (bytesReceived, bytesExpected) {
        console.log(bytesExpected);
        console.log('progress ');
        if (bytesReceived > options.maxPostSize) {
            console.log('bla ');
            req.connection.destroy();
        }
    }).on('end', finish).parse(req,function(err, fields, files) {
            console.log(files);
});
```

now if i try to `console.log` -> `err , fields , or files` it doesnt work .

an the only event that is being emitted is progress .

Comment: Note: It's not just similar to `bodyParser()`. Connect/Express [uses `formidable`](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/multipart.html) for `multipart` requests.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski well thanks ..! this only makes me happy to post what i face and solve here  .. thanks again .

Answer (score 2):

if you use `app.use(express.bodyParser())`
is equivalent to:

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.multipart());
```

the multipart use formidable, so events doesn't trigger,you can remove `app.use(express.multipart());` then you can use formidable object.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the `parse` function . To solve this you need to not use the `bodyParser` .
So let's assume that i have a route `/files` which only recives a post request then you need to disable the `bodyParser` just for that route like so :

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){

  // important .. this will skip body parser to avoide issues with formidable 

    if((req.path == '/file' ||req.path == '/file/') &&req.method === 'POST'){
   // GET , PUT , DELETE ,etc... will have bodyParser ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        return next();
      }
    express.bodyParser(req,res,next);
    next();
});
```